# Implicit Callback not found on this server - react and node express - deploy on Azure

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, azure-web-app-service, okta

I've an issue with the deployment of my react app on Azure web app service.

I've followed this guide:  https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/10/build-a-basic-crud-app-with-node-and-react in local environment it works, but when I've tried to deploy on Azure app service the login with okta doesn't work.

So let me explain. I've uploaded node express server on Azure node app service. The react frontend i've uploaded the "npm run build" result in an other Azure app service.

I've added the Login redirect URI and trusted origins (cors) on okta admin panel.

But during the login the online version of my app replay this issue: "Not Found The requested URL /implicit/callback was not found on this server." and the URL is " https://supportexor.azurewebsites.net/implicit/callback*id_token=qwerqwerqwerqwerqwerqwer" .

In App.js

```
<Route path="/implicit/callback" component={ImplicitCallback} />
```

In index.js

```
const oktaConfig = {
  issuer: ...,
  redirect_uri: .../implicit/callback,
  client_id: ...,
};
```

I would like to see the "SecureRoute" after the login into my app.

Comment: Could you post more details about your deployments and the route configuration? I don't think to deploy the react frontend to another Azure App serice instance is necessary. You can deploy them in one same node app service via `express.static` with a non-conflict route name.

Comment: Hello Peter, I've solved this issue by change Azure App Service from Linux to Windows. And now it works. 
But I have a problem with server (node express) in an Azure App Service Linux (node)